# Custom encrypt and decrypt of Unix Timestamp

Tags: javascript, typescript

Result are not the same and the current referenceCode use is in Utc singapore time

Sample input value
`const referenceCode = "1680698995321";`

Encrypt Function

```
const encryptCode = (referenceNo: string) => {
        const refCode = referenceNo.slice(6);
        const refModified = referenceNo.slice(0, 6) + "0".repeat(7);
        const refInt = parseInt(refModifie`your text`d);
        const date = new Date(refInt);
        const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString("fil-PH", { month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit", year: "2-digit" }).replace(/\//g, '');
        return `${formattedDate}-${refCode}`;
    }
```

Decrypt function

```
const decryptCode = (encryptedCode: string) => {
        const dateRef = encryptedCode.slice(0, 6);
        const dateCode = encryptedCode.slice(7);
        const dateMonth = dateRef.slice(0, 2);
        const dateDay = dateRef.slice(2, 4);
        const dateYear = dateRef.slice(4);
        const dateString = `${dateMonth}/${dateDay}/${dateYear} 8:00:00 UTC`;
        const date = new Date(dateString);
        const timestamp  = date.getTime();
        const result = timestamp.toString().slice(0, 6) + "0".repeat(7)
        return parseInt(result) + parseInt(dateCode);
    }

usage:

console.log(encryptCode(referenceCode)); // 040523-8995321
console.log(decryptCode(encryptCode(referenceCode)); //1680688995321

referenceCode === decrypted code // 1680698995321 === 1680688995321

the result is false
```

Comment: If you just wanna convert a unix timestamp into some other form and back, can you explain why you're bringing days, months and years into this? Shouldn't this be a purely arithmetical operation?

Comment: UTC singepore time is not really a thing. UTC = UTC, and Unix timestamps are in UTC.